# Proving a simple connected graph is a tree if adding an edge between two existing vertices of T creates exactly one cycle

Tags: graph-theory, trees

When proving a simple connected graph is a tree if adding an edge between two existing vertices of T creates exactly one cycle, is it sufficient to just remove that edge that created a cycle, then it since that results in a graph with no cycles, therefore it must be a tree graph by definition?

Original statement to prove:
Prove a simple connected graph T is a tree if and only if adding an edge between two existing vertices of T creates exactly one cycle.

Comment: If only you want to prove the implication, not the equivalence.

Comment: How do you deal with the complete graph?

Comment: I give one summary for the chat between OP and A.S which has [one valuable image](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8438683#8438683) for explanation. If the original graph $G$ has one cycle $C$. Then take arbitrary 2 adjacent vertices $v,w$ (we can also take one pair not adjacent. For simplicity, I assume adjacent) inside this cycle. Then 2 cycles are created. One is the multiedge $(v,w)$, while the other is $C-\{v,w\}+\{v,w\}^{(*)}$ where the superscript $(*)$ shows whether the edge is in the original graph. This is contradiction. So $G$ is acyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is not valid because it fails to prove that the graph is acyclic.  The non sequitur is in the following:

> $\dots$just remove that edge that created a cycle, then it since that results in a graph with no cycles

Notice that the statement doesn't follow.  Also, notice that adding an edge to any connected graph will create a cycle.  You must use the fact that exactly $1$ cycle is generated as a result.

Hint: Argue by contradiction.  Assume the graph has a cycle.  When you connect two vertices of the cycle, how many cycles are created?

Comment: Ok..so can I use what I wrote as a proof or what for the converse

Comment: Sorry, I had misread the question, and it took me a few minutes to regain my composure.

Comment: For proving if T is a tree then adding an edge between 2 vertices creates exactly one cycle I used the definition that 2 vertices in T have exactly one path and so if I add a new edge it creates exactly one cycle. For the converse I did, since there is only one cycle in graph there is two paths from v to w in T, so if I remove one edge, the number of paths from v to w decreases by 1, so then its a tree. Sooo I can't remove an edge and just say the number of paths from v to w decreased to 1?

Comment: The problem is that the hypothesis does not tell you that there is one cycle in the entire graph.  It only tells you that adding an edge *adds* exactly $1$ cycle to the graph.

Comment: well its an if and only if statement, don't I have to prove if adding an edge between two existing vertices of T creates exactly one cycle

Comment: I think i should write the original statement to prove, oops oversight on my part

Comment: @DJ_ Yes, that part of the proof is correct.

Comment: Ok which part is incorrect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7833/discussion-between-andrew-salmon-and-dj)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Prove that if connected graph $G = (V,E)$ contains a cycle and it is not a clique, then you can always add an edge that will create at least two cycles.
- Let $C \subset E$ be some cycle and $u \notin C$ be a vertex such that there exists two vertices $v_1, v_2 \in C$ with $uv_i \notin E$. Then one of $uv_i$ would create at least two cycles.
- If the previous step is not possible, then the graph is a clique or a clique without a single edge (and adding this missing edge surely would create at least two cycles).

Good luck!